# Django 1.1 - comments - 'render_comment_form' returns TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, exception, django-templates, django-comments

I want to simply render a built-in comment form in a template, using Django's builtin commenting module, but this returns a TemplateSyntaxError Exception.

I need help debugging this error, please, because after googling and using the Django API reference, I'm still not getting any farther.

Info:

This is the template '_post.html'[shortened]:

```
<div id="post_{{ object.id }}">
<h2>
    <a href="{% url post object.id %}">{{ object.title }}</a>
    <small>{{ object.pub_date|timesince }} ago</small>
    </h2>
    {{ object.body }}
    {% load comments %}
    {% get_comment_count for object as comment_count %}
    <p>{{ comment_count }}</p>
    <!-- Returns 0, because no comments available  -->
    {% render_comment_form for object %}
    <!-- Returns TemplateSyntaxError -->
```

This is the Exception output, when rendering:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.comments.views.comments.post_comment'
with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.1  
{% load comments i18n %}
        <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
          {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />{% endif %}
          {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.is_hidden %}
              {{ field }}
            {% else %}
          {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
          <p
            {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
            {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}>
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
```

/posts/urls.py[shortened]:

```
queryset = {'queryset': Post.objects.all(),
            'extra_context' : {"tags" : get_tags}
           }   
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url('^$',                           'object_list',      queryset,
        name='posts'),
    url('^blog/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',   'object_detail',    queryset,
        name='post'),
)
```

/urls.py[shortened]:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'', include('posts.urls')),
    (r'^comments/$', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same exact problem, render_comment_form template tag was triggering it.

The issue is certainly with your URL config, you had it set the same way i did:

```
(r'^comments/$', include('django.contrib.comments.urls'))
```

**The correct way is to remove the '$' after 'comments/':**

```
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls'))
```

Otherwise django can't properly include all necessary urls under the path comments/...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is indicated that it can't find a reverse url for:

```
   django.contrib.comments.views.comments.post_comment
```

So basically something isn't configured right in your urls.  Without being able to see more of how things are setup it's difficult to know exactly what.

Maybe try re-ordering the urls pattern includes in your urls.py, to force the django comments urls to the top?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today.  I was referencing a view in urls.py that I hadn't created yet.

From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse

> As part of working out which URL names
>   map to which patterns, the reverse()
>   function has to import all of your
>   URLconf files and examine the name of
>   each view. This involves importing
>   each view function. If there are any
>   errors whilst importing any of your
>   view functions, it will cause
>   reverse() to raise an error, even if
>   that view function is not the one you
>   are trying to reverse.
>
> Make sure that any views you reference
>   in your URLconf files exist and can be
>   imported correctly. Do not include
>   lines that reference views you haven't
>   written yet, because those views will
>   not be importable.

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying that it found the view `django.contrib.comments.views.comments.post_comment`

but no args () or kwargs{} were passed.

Its not passing a value for object.id into the url.

Take out the url tag and see if the id of the `<div id="post_{{object.id}}">` reflects a proper object.id